# How does the Google's smart updates technology work?

Tags: android, diff, updates, delta

I know the basics: they compute a difference between two versions and send it to the user's device where it is deployed. Precisely, I am interested in 2 questions:

1. What changes were made to the server's software and what changes were made to the Android  Google Play Store application?
2. What algorithm is used to compute difference between the two application's versions?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if google followed any of these approaches, but it is similar to [FOTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOTA_(technology))

Comment: What approaches do you mean exactly? They definitely use delta encoding to compute the difference between two files.

Comment: I meant approaches used in FOTA

Comment: I highly doubt that Google is interested in disclosing these details.

Comment: Probably you are right, but they use Courgette to update Chrome and it is available online (source code + brief documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it seems that they use GDIFF algorithm that computes differences between streams. More information about GDIFF algorithm and GDIFF format here: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-gdiff-19970901, http://gdiff.codeplex.com/.